# Java Spark. VectorAssembler dont accept String and Null

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset

I have a big project with Spark using Java. I read a csv file with more than 1.000.000 rows and one column is a String.

When i try to do a VectorAssembler to use a ML algorith i have an error because the column "Moon" is a String.

So im trying to transform this String to a Integer with this:

```
Dataset<Row> moons = typedMoons.withColumn("Moon", typedMoons.col("Moon").cast("Integer"));
```

But when i do this i get a Null value in that column.

So im trying to na.fill() with Java:

```
        Dataset<Row> typedMoonsfinal = typedMoons.na().fill("Moon", typedMoons.col("Moon"));
```

But im not using well fill().

Some recommendations to pull this problem or other ways?

Thank so much and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just convert a string into an int, unless it's the string representation of a number, like "1234". "Moon" is not a number.

What you need to do is use a [StringIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/ml-features.html#stringindexer) to create a correlation between your string labels and a number. Iif you pass your string column through a StringIndexer, it will create a new integer column with the same value for every string in the original column. So all the rows with the "Moon" value will have for example the value 1 in the new column, or all the rows the the "Sun" value will have for example the value 2 in the new column.

You can use this new integer column in your VectorAssembler.